# How can I reencode a video's audio when it was recorded in stereo with a mono source?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have a video that I recorded with an interface using an XLR microphone (mono). The video recording software (Simple Screen Recorder), and my PulseAudio all saw that as a stereo source. Now I have a video with a stereo stream but only one audio channel. How can I correct this so sound plays from both speakers? Currently sound only plays from the left speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to correct this is to use ffmpeg, using `-c:v copy` to leave the video screen alone and `-map_channel` to mark the new video as being stereo.

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/in.mkv -map_channel 0.1.0 -c:v copy /tmp/out.mkv
```